# How to sort a realm Results based on a boolean property

Tags: swift, realm, resultset, realm-mobile-platform

I have tried the sorting with custom pattern. But as it returns an array. It's not helpful. 
As I need the return type to be Results.

Ex: Consider following:

```
class A:Object {
    dynamic var name: String = "abc"
    dynamic var isStrong: Bool = false
}
```

Now how can I sort the above which will produce Results

I did try

```
realm.objects(a.self).sorted({ (o1, o2) -> Bool in
    return o1.isStrong && !o2.isStrong
})
```

This produces a sorted array. But I need a realmResults object. 
Any kind of help is apreiciated.
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `bool` property for sorting a `Results` instance, but you cannot implement a custom sort function that would return `Results`. `Results` only supports sorting based on instance properties of the class or based on several instance properties if you add them to a `SortDescriptor`.

Even though you cannot define custom sorting logic, it seems that your current logic only implements a descending sort based on a single `bool` property, so you can achieve the same results using Realm's built in `sorted(byKeyPath:,ascending:)` method.

```
realm.objects(A.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "isStrong",ascending: false)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding.. And Yes I have been trying this particular way but for some reason i'm still not getting the sorted result.

Comment: Then please update the question with an example input/output pair, since with my test input, this achieved the same results as the code in the question.

Comment: Okay wait i'll add further details for this

Comment: Okay tried it with a different project this worked well. 
I must be having some alternative code messing things here. 
Thanks for the input. :)